# 1672. Richest Customer Wealth. The differeence in these 2 solution is only in line() but can anyone explain how this makes a difference?

Tags: java, arrays

The question and the test cases are in this leetcode link.
https://leetcode.com/problems/richest-customer-wealth/description/
Solution 1 fails in the 3rd test while solution 2 passes all tests; the only difference is in the highlighted line.

Solution1:

```
class Solution {
    public int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {    
        int[] money = new int[accounts.length];
        for(int i=0;i<accounts.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<accounts[i].length;j++){
                money[i] = money[i] + accounts[i][j];
            }
        }
        return max(money);
    }
    static int max(int[] money){
        int great = money[0];
        for(int i=1;i<money.length;i++){
            if(money[i]>money[i-1]){    // This line has problem<<<-----------------------HERE
                great = money[i];
            }
        }
        return great;
    }
}
```

Solution2:

```
class Solution {
    public int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {    
        int[] money = new int[accounts.length];
        for(int i=0;i<accounts.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<accounts[i].length;j++){
                money[i] = money[i] + accounts[i][j];
            }
        }
        return max(money);
    }
    static int max(int[] money){
        int great = money[0];
        for(int i=1;i<money.length;i++){
            if(money[i]>great){          // this line is correct<<<-----------------------HERE
                great = money[i];
            }
        }
        return great;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so you know the problem and solution. What is your actual question here? One line compares an array element with the element in the array on the indey before it, and the other compares an array element to the value saved in a variable. They are obviously different operations.

Comment: Well the second one correctly finds the max of the array by comparing current max value and setting current max if the current iteration is greater than it.  The first one compares current array value to previous array value and assign the value to `great` for no reason.  The difference is really that the first one is wrong and the second one is right

Comment: @Nexevis   There is an If statement that checks if(money[i]>money[i-1]) and assigns value to a great variable, which somehow does not work for the third test.

Comment: Yes because that is clearly not the same thing as `money[i]>great`, one is checking the value of `great` and one is not.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript solution

```
var maximumWealth = function(accounts) {
    let max_wealth = 0;
    accounts.forEach(item_i => {
        let item_i_wealth=0;
        item_i.forEach(item_j => {
            item_i_wealth=item_i_wealth+item_j;
        })
        max_wealth = max_wealth>item_i_wealth ? max_wealth : item_i_wealth;
    })
    return max_wealth
};
```